# Why does Poetry 1.2 create a config file in the wrong location, then complain it's in the wrong location?

Tags: python-poetry

I've installed Poetry 1.2.

I run poetry.

It says `Configuration file exists at ~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry, reusing this directory. Consider moving configuration to ~/Library/Preferences/pypoetry`

I move `config.toml` from `~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry` to `~/Library/Preferences/pypoetry` as instructed.

I run poetry.

It recreates `config.toml` in `~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry` and says `Configuration file exists at ~/Library/Application Support/pypoetry, reusing this directory. Consider moving configuration to ~/Library/Preferences/pypoetry`

Can anyone help me understand this baffling behaviour and telll me how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question because the same thing happened to me. I found [this discussion](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/discussions/6823) on the poetry github page and realised that you need to move the `auth.toml` file as well as the `config.toml`. Running this command in a Terminal should do the trick:

```
 mv /Users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/pypoetry/*.toml /Users/$USER/Library/Preferences/pypoetry
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Still investigating...

Answer (score 0):

The command in the other answer is reversed. It should be:

```
mv /Users/$USER/Library/Preferences/pypoetry/*.toml /Users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/pypoetry/
```

The warning says:

```
Consider moving TOML configuration files to /Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/pypoetry
```